# Kasa dimmer switch w/ two black wires?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light, smart-switch

[image]

I’ve just gone to wire
up my new Kasa dimmer and noticed the existing switch had two black wires and a red running into it.

I installed the Kasa the same way (two black into the black port, red into red, and then neutral and ground accordingly. I’ve just tested and it’s working perfectly but I wanted to make sure that what I did was correct (and more importantly that it’s safe) because I’m an amateur (on my best day)

Comment: Did you take a "before" picture?  Without that, it will be hard to tell...

Comment: Noting the black and two brass screws, the switch at the bottom is clearly a 3-way switch.  That means there's another switch somewhere else that controls the same light.  It happens all the time that people settle into their habits and never, ever use a particular switch... well, if someone ever does, it may cause this switch to malfunction.  This will happen randomly and out of the blue.

Comment: @harper - you’re absolutely right. There’s a second switch (just had to go look for it, didn’t even know it existed) that also controls the same light. It’s a switch we don’t ever use. Do I need to do anything with it? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site Austin. Please [register](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) your account and then [merge](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them so you have access to edit, comment, and accept answers on your own question. Posting multiple responses as answers can result in an automated lock that can prevent others from assisting you.